# Confirm FPGA load with XSVF player

Tags: embedded, xilinx

I have an embedded project with a CPU that programs a Xilinx Spartan3 using an XSVF player via the JTAG pins.  I am looking for a way to confirm **via those JTAG pins** that a valid configuration has been loaded into the FPGA.
The unprogrammed case arises when my system is rebooted in the middle of an update, and on the next boot the device is not programmed.  I know JAMPlayers for Altera chips have a command to confirm that a valid image has been loaded, and I am looking for something similar using XSVF files/players.

Comment: The Spartan III is not non-volatile, wouldn't you *have to* reprogram in in any case if the system re-booted?  Or is the part separately powered?

Comment: All Xilinx FPGAs will have the DONE pin go high when the part is programmed successfully; this pin is usually routed to an LED so it's easy to see. Can "XSVF-player" (I've never used it) poll the DONE register through JTAG? If so, then that's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

The DONE flag is included in the readback value of the JTAG instruction register. This [xilinx answer](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/20071.htm) describes how to check the DONE flag.

The IR bit values are also described in the JTAG section of the Spartan-3 configuration user guide.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the kind of information I was looking for.